# Why do the contribution page amount labels now appear before the amounts?

Tags: contribution-page

All of a sudden in 4.6, contribution pages using the regular "fixed contribution options" (i.e. not using a price set) display the options as:

- **Donor** - $25.00
- **Supporter** - $50.00
- **Champion** - $100.00

and so forth.  This is a sudden change that a client pointed out--the options used to appear as:

- **$25.00** Donor
- **$50.00** Supporter
- **$100.00** Champion

Both are reasonable, but does anyone know why it changed after working this way for years?

Answer (score 3):

I can't find the exact issue or commit at the moment, but these changes were made to standardise the order the of the label and the price. Depending on the type of field used, the price and label were sometimes in a different order.

For example, in 4.4:

[image]

And in 4.6:

[image]

As a sidenote, I think we decided on the order 'Label - Price' because you would normally look at what you wanted to buy, and then how much it is. That made the most sense I think, when choosing ticket options for an event for example.